# Issues with the webbrowser component

Tags: c#, browser, web-crawler

I have a program (C# using VS 2010) that performs browser like activities using `WebBrowser` component.

The purpose of the program is to crawl web pages. The first problem is that after approx. 50 pages I get a JavaScript error (Out of memory (see image))

[image: Script Error]

To ignore this error I use the following command:

```
ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true
```

The above command solves the script error but creates another problem:

I also use `Links.InvokeMember("click");` in order to scroll the page, or click on Ajax links.

So the program gets an error and the `ScriptErrorsSuppressed` disables it, but then the `invoke` stops from clicking on the pages... and the crawling stops.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue ?

Comment: That is a JavaScript error, not a Java error ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are at the mercy of the client code that is downloaded an run in the browser control.  If that is not right then you get leaks and these memory issues.

The only thing I could think to do would be to try disposing of your browser control at some point after a few pages and re-create it and see if this helps.

Comment: Have you tried going a bit further and running the control in a separate process, then re-starting the process periodically.  I know it is crude, but I am not sure what else you can do when the code casusing the problem is outside of your control.

Comment: Tried that... no go... any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to crawl webpages, you really shouldn't be using the webbrowser control. Use the httpWebRequest class and make your request, get the html string, and you can loop through the links and DOM objects of the HTML string using MSHTML, so you give it to mshtml and it will turn that HTML string into a nice object you can loop through (so you don't need to try and parse the links out using string manipulation, you just loop through everything as they are all turned into objects thanks to mshtml).

Of course, this way, all that javascript and what have you will not run, and you won't have to waste bandwidth and time loading all those images and having all those elements drawn to the screen when they are not needed.

Get me? Let me know if you need more help.